# svg element not rendering on html page- angular 5

Tags: html, angular, svg

I am trying to render an svg element on html in angular 5 and i am getting below error.

[image]

This is my svg element.
I got this svg element code by saving a vsdx diagram to svg from ms visio 2016 tool

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by Microsoft Visio, SVG Export testicon.svg Page-1 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/" width="0.905093in" height="2.11139in"
  viewBox="0 0 65.1667 152.02" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st4">
 <v:documentProperties v:langID="1033" v:viewMarkup="false"/>

 <style type="text/css">

  .st1 {fill:#d9f442;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-width:1.25}
  .st2 {stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.2376}
  .st3 {fill:#000000;font-family:Calibri;font-size:0.666664em}
  .st4 {fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;font-size:12px;overflow:visible;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:3}

 </style>

 <g v:mID="0" v:index="1" v:groupContext="foregroundPage">
  <v:userDefs>
   <v:ud v:nameU="PEHideTags"/>
  </v:userDefs>
  <title>Page-1</title>
  <v:pageProperties v:drawingScale="1" v:pageScale="1" v:drawingUnits="19" v:shadowOffsetX="9" v:shadowOffsetY="-9"/>
  <v:layer v:name="Equipment" v:index="0"/>
  <g id="group5-1" transform="translate(1.25,-25.4369)" v:mID="5" v:groupContext="group" v:layerMember="0">
   <v:custProps>
    <v:cp v:nameU="Description" v:lbl="Description" v:type="0" v:sortKey="0" v:langID="1033"/>
    <v:cp v:nameU="Material" v:lbl="Material" v:type="0" v:sortKey="1" v:langID="1033"/>
    <v:cp v:nameU="Manufacturer" v:lbl="Manufacturer" v:type="0" v:sortKey="2" v:langID="1033"/>
    <v:cp v:nameU="Model" v:lbl="Model" v:type="0" v:sortKey="3" v:langID="1033"/>
   </v:custProps>
   <v:userDefs>
    <v:ud v:nameU="TextCH" v:prompt="Determines text control handle visibility." v:val="VT0(5):26"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="visVersion" v:val="VT0(15):26"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="SOLSH" v:val="VT4({D7D7DB7E-3668-43e5-AF97-97F58AB229A5})"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="ShapeClass" v:val="VT4(Equipment)"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="PEComponentTag" v:val="VT4(E-0)"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="PETagNumber"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="PETagFormat" v:prompt="E-0" v:val="VT4(Equipment)"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="PEHideTag"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="PEPageHideTags" v:val="VT0(0):26"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="PELayout" v:val="VT0(31):26"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="CPMSetList" v:prompt="Description,Material,Manufacturer,Model" v:val="VT4(Equipment)"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="TextCH" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(0):26"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="PEComponentTag" v:prompt="" v:val="VT4(E-13)"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="PETagNumber" v:prompt="" v:val="VT0(13):26"/>
    <v:ud v:nameU="PETagFormat" v:prompt="E-13" v:val="VT0(0):26"/>
   </v:userDefs>
   <title>Tray column.18</title>
   <desc>NGL</desc>
   <g id="shape6-2" v:mID="6" v:groupContext="shape" v:layerMember="0">
    <title>Sheet.6</title>
    <path d="M-0 136.35 A31.8476 19.0818 -180 0 0 62.67 136.35 L62.67 42.35 A31.8476 19.0818 -180 0 0 0 42.35 L0 136.35
        Z" class="st1"/>
   </g>
   <g id="shape7-4" v:mID="7" v:groupContext="shape" v:layerMember="0" transform="translate(0,-94)">
    <title>Sheet.7</title>
    <v:userDefs>
     <v:ud v:nameU="visKeywords"
       v:val="VT4(Tray,dashed,symbol,column,Equipment,Vessels,process,plant,design,mechanical,drawings,autoclaves)"/>
     <v:ud v:nameU="visVersion" v:val="VT0(15):26"/>
    </v:userDefs>
    <path d="M0 152.02 L62.67 152.02" class="st2"/>
   </g>
   <g id="shape8-7" v:mID="8" v:groupContext="shape" v:layerMember="0" transform="translate(0,-31.3333)">
    <title>Sheet.8</title>
    <v:userDefs>
     <v:ud v:nameU="visKeywords"
       v:val="VT4(Tray,dashed,symbol,column,Equipment,Vessels,process,plant,design,mechanical,drawings,autoclaves)"/>
     <v:ud v:nameU="visVersion" v:val="VT0(15):26"/>
    </v:userDefs>
    <path d="M0 152.02 L62.67 152.02" class="st2"/>
   </g>
   <g id="shape9-10" v:mID="9" v:groupContext="shape" v:layerMember="0" transform="translate(0,-78.3333)">
    <title>Sheet.9</title>
    <v:userDefs>
     <v:ud v:nameU="visKeywords"
       v:val="VT4(Tray,dashed,symbol,column,Equipment,Vessels,process,plant,design,mechanical,drawings,autoclaves)"/>
     <v:ud v:nameU="visVersion" v:val="VT0(15):26"/>
    </v:userDefs>
    <path d="M0 152.02 L62.67 152.02" class="st2"/>
   </g>
   <g id="shape10-13" v:mID="10" v:groupContext="shape" v:layerMember="0" transform="translate(0,-47)">
    <title>Sheet.10</title>
    <v:userDefs>
     <v:ud v:nameU="visKeywords"
       v:val="VT4(Tray,dashed,symbol,column,Equipment,Vessels,process,plant,design,mechanical,drawings,autoclaves)"/>
     <v:ud v:nameU="visVersion" v:val="VT0(15):26"/>
    </v:userDefs>
    <path d="M0 152.02 L62.67 152.02" class="st2"/>
   </g>
   <g id="shape5-16" v:mID="5" v:groupContext="groupContent" v:layerMember="0">
    <v:textBlock v:margins="rect(4,4,4,4)"/>
    <v:textRect cx="31.3333" cy="168.655" width="64" height="17.6036"/>
    <text x="24.55" y="171.06" class="st3" v:langID="1033"><v:paragraph v:horizAlign="1"/><v:tabList/></text>   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

If i paste the above svg element in a plain html file, i am able to render the 
image but i am unable to render in angular component html page.

Can any one tell me how do i render this svg element in the angular component html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom Visio elements (`<v:* ... >`) elements in that SVG are confusing Angular.

If the SVG is just used as a static file, then remove the Visio elements. You can either do this manually, or you can run it through a tool like [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo).